# Host name is unvalid

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to call a web service from a server but didn't get the correct response on Serial Monitor arduino, i get the error "hostname is invalid". Below is the code along with the result:

Thanks @Edgar Bonet, i have tried as you suggested. Following is the correction and the result, now the error is "The request verb is invalid"
    {

```
EthernetClient client1;


//second 
int inChar;
char outBuf[64];
char params[65];

Serial.print(F("Method 2 connecting..."));

if(client1.connect("198.38.93.76",807) == 1)
{
Serial.println(F("connected"));

// send the header
client1.println(F("POST /JMS_Auth_WebService.asmx HTTP/1.1"));
client1.println(F("Host: 198.38.93.76"));
client1.println(F("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"));
client1.println(F("Content-Length: 315"));
client1.println(F("Connection: keep-alive"));
client1.println(F("SOAPAction: \"http://jbscrms.com/GetThresholdOfDeviceForSaud\"")); 
client1.println();

client1.println(F("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"));
client1.println(F("<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"));
client1.println(F("<soap:Body>"));
client1.println(F("<GetThresholdOfDeviceForSaud xmlns=\"http://jbscrms.com\">"));
client1.println(F("<Device_id>2</Device_id>"));
client1.println(F("</GetThresholdOfDeviceForSaud>"));
client1.println(F("</soap:Body>"));
client1.println(F("</soap:Envelope>"));


Serial.println(F("Done Calling New Web Service"));

} 
else
{
Serial.println(F("failed"));

}

int connectLoop = 0;

while(client1.connected())
{

if(client1.available())
{
inChar = client1.read();


Serial.write(inChar);
connectLoop = 0;
}

delay(1);
connectLoop++;
if(connectLoop > 30000)
{
Serial.println();
Serial.println(F("Timeout"));
client1.stop();
}
}

Serial.println();
Serial.println(F("disconnecting."));
client1.stop();
}
```

Following is the result on Serial monitor arduino

```
Ready
Entered<R_TempData>29</R_TempData>
<R_smokeData>226</R_TempData>
<R_humidityData>36</R_TempData>
Method 2 connecting...connected
Done Calling New Web Service
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf

-8
    Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
    X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    Date: Fri, 11 Nov 2016 07:23:28 GMT

Content-Length: 0

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Fri, 11 Nov 2016 07:23:28 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 326

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

disconnecting.
```

Comment: Either `print("Foo: bar\r\n");` or `println("Foo: bar");`. print**ln** adds the "\r\n" for you.

Comment: You need to remove the port (`:807`) from the `Host` entry. You can probably remove that entire line. PS. there should be only one space before `   HTTP/1.1`, not three.

Comment: Also, remove protocol, host and port from the POST line: `client1.println(F("POST /JMS_Auth_WebService.asmx HTTP/1.1"));` And your SOAPAction line is incomplete: the code as posted cannot compile. Please, post here the _actual_ code you are using.

Comment: Your `Content-Length` header is wrong. You are not sending 1000 bytes of data.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you need a \r\n between the Post statement and the HTTP statement.
2. Why are you including the Port number in the Host name?
3. Your SOAPAction line is wrong, but I guess that's a typo in the post.

Comment: Thanks @Matt . You suggested the same as Edhar Bonet. I tried but didn't get a correct response. I have posted the error above.